# Jasper Reports Dynamic Reports - DRException in HTTPServlets

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I have a servlet that calls the Jasper report class.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ReportGeneratorModel.generateReport();
        response.sendRedirect("report.jsp");
}
```

The ReportGeneratorModel calls a MYSQL database and then generates a report.

```
public static void generateReport() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cleanhandsreport?"+"user=Manager&password=PASSWORD");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
    report
      .columns(
          Columns.column("HospitalID", "HospitalID", DataTypes.stringType()),
          Columns.column("GroupID", "GroupID", DataTypes.stringType()), 
          Columns.column("HandWashViolation", "HandWashViolation", DataTypes.stringType()))
      .title(//title of the report
          Components.text("CleanHands Report")
          .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
          .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
          .setDataSource("SELECT HospitalID, GroupID, Time, HandWashViolation FROM report", 
                                  connection);

    try {
                //show the report
        report.show();

                //export the report to a pdf file
        report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("report.pdf"));
    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am receiving the following error

```
    Jan 31, 2015 2:56:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rbccps.cleanhands.report.controller.ReportHomeServletController] in context with path [/CleanHandsReport] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at rbccps.cleanhands.report.controller.ReportHomeServletController.doPost(ReportHomeServletController.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have all the jar files from the dynamicreports-4.0.0/lib folder and also the dynamicreports-core-4.0.0.jar in my Classpath.

When I try the report as an stand alone Java Application, everything works fine.

I tried to add some logs in the generateReport() method. None of them is getting printed, even though they are placed at the top of the method.

Any pointers on the problem is much appreciated.

Comment: have you added jar for pdf export(like itextpdf.jar)?

Comment: Hi Wahab, itextpdf-5.5.0.jar is available in my build path.

Comment: I got the web application running. 
The problem was with the jar file placement. 
For a web-app, all the jars should be placed within the WEB-INF/lib directory for Tomcat to read/recognize the jars.

Comment: glad that you got the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the web application running. The problem was with the jar file placement. For a web-app, all the jars should be placed within the WEB-INF/lib directory for Tomcat to read/recognize the jars.

I Kindly request the Admins to CLOSE the question. Cheers.